# PrimeNG Auto-Complete with inputStyleClass

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using primeNG Auto complete and added inputStyleClass="form-control"..the issue is the icon goes to the next line..see image below

[image]

Itt should align next to the box, how do i do that?

**HTML**

```
   <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                      [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('gatewayRole').touched || ersaForm.get('gatewayRole').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('gatewayRole').valid
                                     }">
                                    <label for="gatewayRoleId" class="control-label">Gateway Role</label>
                                    <p-autoComplete  [suggestions]="iRole"  formControlName="Role"    inputStyleClass="form-control" id="RoleId" placeholder="Role (required)" (completeMethod)="searchRole($event)" [style]="{'width':'85%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'85%'}" field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>

                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add this to my auto complete:

> formControlName="phone" [style]="{'width': '100%','display':
>   'inline-flex','height':'34px'}"

```
  <p-autoComplete  [suggestions]="iRole"  formControlName="Role"    [spellcheck]="true" inputStyleClass="form-control"  id="RoleId" placeholder="Role (required)" (completeMethod)="searchRole($event)"  [style]="{'width': '100%','display': 'inline-flex','height':'34px'}"  field="name" dataKey="id" [dropdown]="true"></p-autoComplete>
```